# How do I control the modes of the root directory created with mke2fs?

Tags: ext2

mke2fs has a root_owner option. But it seems to lack an option to set the mode of the root directory.

My goal is to create a file system, mount it (loopback), and fill it. If the owner is the root, which I want eventually, then I can't write the content into it. If the owner is me, I can write the content, but then I've got this unwanted uid/gid for when I mount the thing and put it to work.

Is there any solution other than chmod once mounted for production?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [genext2fs](http://genext2fs.sourceforge.net/) to generate an ext[234] filesystem image as a non root user without having to mount it.

Comment: It crashes on large images, I started there.